# How to create a date range from a list of dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've tried searching for an answer to my question but all the scenarios that have been covered previously are slightly different. Apologies If I've missed one that does answer this.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID     Date
35  2015-06-01
35  2015-06-02
35  2015-06-03
35  2015-06-06
40  2015-06-07
40  2015-06-08
40  2015-06-09
40  2015-06-10
40  2015-06-13
35  2015-06-14
35  2015-06-15
35  2015-06-16
35  2015-06-17
```

And I would like to get it in the form:

```
ID   DateFrom      DateTo
35  2015-06-01    2015-06-07
40  2015-06-07    2015-06-14
35  2015-06-14    2015-06-18
```

However, every solution that I can think of or have seen (row_number(), min / max, lag etc) only returns the following

```
ID   DateFrom      DateTo
35  2015-06-01    2015-06-18
40  2015-06-07    2015-06-14
```

i.e the date range for ID 35 is taking the min and max of the dates from the first table. It seems like this should be easy but I'm completely stuck.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Isn't the `DateTo` for the first row supposed to be `2015-06-30`?

Comment: and is this mysql or sql server?  It makes a difference for the approach.  This link, for example, shows you how to inspect the next value:http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/  I think you'll need to do something like this if you want date ranges for consecutive IDs.

Comment: Do all ID 35's have four rows and all 40's have five rows?

Comment: Why do you want the first date of the change ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ROW_NUMBER` with `MIN` and `MAX`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8aab/2/0)

```
WITH CteGrp AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date)
              - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT 
    ID,
    DateFrom = MIN([Date]),
    DateTo = MAX([Date])
FROM CteGrp
GROUP BY ID, grp
ORDER BY DateFrom
```

**RESULT**

```
| ID |   DateFrom |     DateTo |
|----|------------|------------|
| 35 | 2015-06-01 | 2015-06-06 |
| 40 | 2015-06-07 | 2015-06-13 |
| 35 | 2015-06-14 | 2015-06-17 |
```

Comment: Amazing! This is perfect. Thanks felix

Comment: This explains not only building date ranges, but other data ranged. http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2009/08/27/sql-and-contiguous-data-ranges.aspx